# jQuery $.each with $.wait

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have within my attempts, made too many API requests causing myself to receive a temporary API ban. Below is what I am doing:

```
$.each(api_field, function(index, sector ) {
    "use strict";
    $.each(sector, function( key, values) {
        $.getJSON("URL", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("body").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

My script runs through 62 URL's and for each API request I need to sleep for 1-5 seconds. How can I use the jQuery `.wait()` function to not request all data in a mere second(s)?

**NOTE:** My script fully works as it is, I just need to add a delay per request.

Comment: be aware that this is a async request.

Comment: Why two $.each used before ajax.? Can you tell what is the purpose of second each from top.

Comment: To loop through my fields array with is multi-dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery. Use `setTimeout`:

```
var i = 0;
$.each(api_field, function (index, sector) {
    "use strict";
    $.each(sector, function (key, values) {
      i++;
      setTimeout(function () {           
        $.getJSON("URL", function (result) {
          $.each(result, function (i, field) {
            $("body").append(field + " ");
          });
        });
      }, 1000 * i); // Or 5000
    });
  });
```

Comment: My understanding is that `setTimeout()` isn't very cross-browser friendly, especially if the user changes tab? I've had havock with `setTimeout()` in the past...

Comment: Where did you get that? `setTimeout` is [supported in all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Browser_compatibility). Don't really understand your other issue with user changing tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I had already faced this in my past project.
I used `.delay()` to delay the iterating process.

If you'll use `.delay()`

```
$.each(api_field, function(index, sector ) {
    "use strict";
    $.each(sector, function( key, values) {
        $.getJSON("URL", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){

                $("body").delay(5000*i).queue(function(next){
                    $(this)..append(field + " ");
                    next();
                });

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Change the time to what you want `1000 = 1s` .

Comment: The delay seems to be in the wrong place... Shouldn't it be on or before the request URL? The aim is to delay each `$.getJSON`, I am still setting off their API limit at present, this is just delaying appending the information to the body.

Answer (score -1):

You can use setTimeout to have a delay:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.getJSON("URL", function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("body").append(field + " ");
        });
     });
},1000*index);//<---index from outermost each.
```

It will make a delay for each iteration for one second.